# Creating a Github repository from local terminal

Tags: git, github

How can I create a Github repository from a local terminal?

**Update :**

We have to create repository and upload the data from one application to github , with out storing any data in application system ... It is possible

Actually , many users will login in to this application . They will enter code and check result in preview frame . Here the user able to store this code in to github .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [hub](https://github.com/defunkt/hub).

```
hub create repo
```

Comment: Error : 'create' must be run from inside a git repository

Comment: And the problem with that would be??? Just create one with `git init` and then call `hub create`.

Comment: Michael Wild : We have to create repository and upload the data  from one application to github , with out storing any data in application system ... It is possible ?

Comment: I really doubt that *that* is possible. You couldn't use `hub` anymore (but instead directly use the [github API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create)), and you couldn't use git itself to push the data, you would need something where you could send the data from memory. Perhaps you can achieve this with [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/), I honestly don't know.

Answer (score 7):

You don't create a Github repository, but create a Git repository. This can then be used with Github as a remote. If you created your repository on Github, you can use the following commands to connect your local repository with the Github remote:

```
$ mkdir ~/Hello-World
# Creates a directory for your project called "Hello-World" in your user directory

$ cd ~/Hello-World
# Changes the current working directory to your newly created directory

$ git init# Sets up the necessary Git files
# Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/you/Hello-World/.git/


$ git remote add origin https://github.com/username/Hello-World.git
# Creates a remote named "origin" pointing at your GitHub repository

$ git push origin master
# Sends your commits in the "master" branch to GitHub
```

From: https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo

Comment: I am getting error :
fatal: https://github.com/srinivas47n/git.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Comment: @srinivas Have you created the repository on Github, before you pushed the changes?

Comment: no i didnt crated . i want create from terminal of my local system

Comment: can you please check updated question

Comment: @srinivas If you want to store your commit data on Github, you have to create a repository there. You cannot create a repository remotely on the Github servers from your local terminal, unless you use the Github API.

Answer (score 1):

[Defunkt's `hub` tool](https://github.com/defunkt/hub) can do that

Answer (score -1):

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server
A complete tutorial to set up git from local server.

Comment: That has nothing to do with github

Comment: @NevikRehnel, github also use git command, so it should work.

Comment: But it does not answer the OP's question. He asked how to create a repo on github, not how to set up a git server

Comment: @NevikRehnel, Thanks for your update. But, He asked how to create a repo on github from a local termianl.